# Html: put text in semitransparent div

Tags: html, css

I want to put text in semitransparent div, and here is what I've done.

**Html**

```
<div class="overlay_image">
   <div>
       <h1 class ="slogan">In div</h1>
   </div>
</div>
<h1 class ="slogan">Out of div</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay_image {
    width: 800px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #0066CC;
    opacity: 0.35;
}

.slogan{
     opacity: 1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fifiteen82726/bsLy3mfj/1/)

However, I want the color in `div` is equal to the color out of `div`. I don't want the words `In div` become semitransparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rgba()` for the background. This way, only the background will be transparent, but the contents of the element are unaffected.

```
.overlay_image {
    width: 800px;
    height: 160px;
    background: rgba(0, 102, 204, 0.35); /* use rgba */
    /*opacity: 0.35;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly.